# Do static members ever get garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, static-members

Do static member variables ever get garbage collected?

For example, let's use the following class.

```
public class HasStatic {
    private static List<string> shared = new List<string>();

}
```

And supposed that it's used like this:

```
//Startup
{
HasStatic a = new HasStatic();
HasStatic b = new HasStatic();
HasStatic c = new HasStatic();
HasStatic d = new HasStatic();
//Something
}
//Other code
//Things deep GC somewhere in here
HasStatic e = new HasStatic();
```

When `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are garbage collected does the static member `shared` get collected as well? Could `e` possibly get a new instance of `shared`?

Comment: Keep in mind that `a.shared[1]` will have the same value as `b.shared[1]`, and that this element of `HasStatic` can also be referenced via `HasStatic.shared[1]`. (Assuming, of course, that there are at least 2 elements in the `shared` list.)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

No, static members are associated with the Type, which is associated with the AppDomain it's loaded in.

Note that there doesn't have to be *any* instances of `HasStatic` for the class to be initialized and the `shared` variable to have a reference to a `List<string>`.

Unless you're considering situations where AppDomains get unloaded, static variables can be regarded as GC roots forever. (Of course, if something changes the value of `HasStatic.shared` to reference a different instance, the first instance *may* become eligible for garbage collection.)

Comment: +1. I was pretty certain about this, but would have needed to test to verify. ...maybe even look it up in my *C# in Depth* book! LOL

Comment: There are two exceptions that should be mentioned. Anything referenced via `WeakReference` can be garbage collected, as are any static members instantiated as `ThreadLocal` whose thread terminates.

Comment: This is a really old answer, I know, but I have a follow-up question, Jon: Given your last remark in parenthesis: What decides if the original instance is eligible for garbage collection or not?

Comment: @ChrisRidge: The same as anything else: whether there's any way of getting to the object, basically.

Comment: What if you set the static member to `null`? From what I've been reading, this will make it available for GC.

Comment: @DiskCrasher: Well, that would mean that the static variable would no longer *stop* an object variable from being garbage collected, yes.

Answer (score 30):

The only thing I would add to Jon's excellent answer is that CLR 4 supports "collectible assemblies". If you dynamically generate a collectible assembly then the statics of its types go away when the assembly is garbage collected.

See this msdn article for a brief overview of the feature:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: How well do those work in practice? Isn't there a lot of (user)code that caches reflection data and thus keeps the types and assemblies alive?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: If user code caches data that keeps a larger object alive then The System Works. That's the whole point of garbage collection, is to keep reachable stuff alive. The justification for collectible assemblies is the opposite problem: we would like to be able to generate temporary code in temporary assemblies that goes away when it is all unreachable.  We could not do that before collectible assemblies.

Comment: I mean that code accidentally keeps that collectible assembly alive by caching type related information that's obsolete once the type were to no longer exist. I've created a question since this is a bit too complicated to discuss in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601502/caching-reflection-data

Comment: @Eric: It may also be worth mentioning WeakReferences and ThreadLocal members as well, then.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: How can I check if handler (handler method class) is member of collectible assembly?

Comment: @HugoUchoBruno: That sure sounds like a great question to post on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: NP – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237938/how-can-i-check-if-handler-handler-method-class-is-member-of-collectible-assem.