# When is a singleton class object garbage collected?

Tags: garbage-collection, singleton, singleton-methods

If a single instance of class is created using singleton pattern, if it is not referenced for a long time, if a GC finds an unrooted tree whose leaf is the Singleton instance, will it be garbage collected?

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, singleton pattern is implemented by defining a private static field, a private construtor and a static method that returns the field. So, the question boils down to: a static field is garbaged collected?

The answer is no, at least according to this SO answer: [Do static members ever get garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600093/do-static-members-ever-get-garbage-collected)

So, even if there is no other references to the static field it will not be GC'ed.

Comment: How about in the case when the Singleton is implemented with the use of Enum ?

Comment: See that, in the original question, if we have a static field in a class referencing an object and we set it to null then the object previously referenced by it can be GC'ed, but doing so we break the singleton pattern.

Comment: What about for Swift? Anyone have any tests to verify this? Or any official apple docs?