# Does using a static member inside a non-static method cause memory leakage?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, static

Does the `DoSomething()` method cause memory leakage?

```
public static class AppContext
{
   public static int ApplicationStateId {get; set} 
   ...
} 
public class MyService
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
        ....
        if(AppContext.ApplicationStateId == 1) 
        {
             //do something
        } 
     }
}
```

---

```
var service = new MyService();
service.DoSomething();
```

> This means that static variables and everything they reference will never be garbage collected.

Michael said in [8 Ways You can Cause Memory Leaks in .NET](https://michaelscodingspot.com/ways-to-cause-memory-leaks-in-dotnet/).

Comment: Its not a memory leak, but it is persistent until the process dies. A memory leak is when you create something and then never free its memory after not using it anymore.

Comment: Static member are [not garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6600093/1997232), so they are potential reasons of memory leak (e.g. static events, singletons/instance holders, etc.). In your example, it's just `int`, which is value type, so no, that can't be a reason of leak.

Comment: @John: does `service` free by GC after using it? or freeing `service` delayed until application ends?

Comment: MyService will free whenever its scope ends, such as at the end of a function. AppContext will continue to exist.

Comment: (Note that a variable's scope has no relation to when it might be collected. Variables that are still in scope can be collected, if they're not used beyond that point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "leak" here; this is simply the expected behavior. Yes, anything that is reachable via a static field will will not be collected by GC, but this is usually correct in terms of some kind of global state. By "leak", we're usually referring to *unexpected or inexplicable* memory retention. The most common scenario there is with static *events* which sound like a great idea, but make it very easy to keep entire segments of long-redundant objects alive. For example:

```cs
SomeType.SomeStaticEvent += obj.HandleTheThing;
```

which now means that the object from `obj` is now retained forever (or at least until the delegate is explicitly removed from the event), and anything that `obj` can see: is now retained forever, etc.

---

In the case shown in the question, there *aren't* even any objects - just an integer. I don't think you need to worry about the cost of retaining an integer over the duration of an app-domain, especially if your app-domain *requires* that integer to be known for the duration.

I'd be more concerned about things like concurrency - whether that means "multiple current user stations", or low level details like volatility and register usage of fields.

Comment: Thank you, I used `CurrentUserStationId` to explain my question, you are right, I changed the `CurrentUserStationId` to `ApplicationStateId`:)